# Distinguish between planes and helicopters with ADS-B messages

Tags: ads-b

Is there a way to reliably distinguish between planes and helicopters using an ADS-B receiver only (no aircraft database)?

I think of using heuristics like "if ground speed > 250 mph then it's a plane", but I would like to find some good heuristics to be sure to identify helicopters correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADSB transmits [wake vortex information](https://mode-s.org/decode/content/ads-b/2-identification.html#tb:adsb_id_wake_category), and TC=4,CA=7 is for rotorcraft.

[This is called the "emitter category" by ICAO](https://www.icao.int/NACC/Documents/Meetings/2019/ADSBOUT/ADSB-OUT-M-WP16.pdf) and some other sources, a rotorcraft is A7.